# How do I test Windows 8 "pinned sites" without windows 8?

Tags: testing, windows-8, pinned-site

So I don't have Windows 8 and I don't intend to get it any time soon. However, I do want to provide the various "pinned sites" features to Windows 8 users who use my website.

Is there a way to test these things without getting hold of any other Windows 8 device?